# How to remotely execute linux commands on different machines from a single machine?

Tags: linux, unix, ssh, command, scp

I have around 50 ubuntu machines on which I need to run below commands:

```
sudo apt-get install htop
sudo scp -r todd@machineA.host.com:/home/todd/pip /tmp/
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo pip install --no-index --find-links="file:///tmp/pip/" kazoo
sudo scp -r todd@machineA.host.com:/home/todd/parallel-gnu.tar /tmp/
sudo su
cd /tmp
tar -xvf parallel-gnu.tar
cd parallel-20101112/
sudo ./configure && make && make install
sudo mkdir /appholder
sudo chown -R golden /appholder/
sudo mkdir -p /opt/lnp
sudo scp todd@machineA.host.com:/keeper/data/release/comp.tar.gz /opt/lnp/
sudo chown -R golden /opt/lnp/
sudo mkdir -p /comp/core
sudo chown -R golden /comp/core
```

Now one way is I can directly login to all 50 machines and run these commands manually and it will work for sure. I don't want to do that as it is very tedious.

Let's say out of those 50  machines, I can run above commands manually on one machine1 to install everything on that box, now from that machine1 can I run all above commands on remaining 49 machines which can install all above things for me? I can keep typing my password if needed

Below are the machine information:

```
machine1.host.com to machine50.host.com
```

And my username is `todd` and also I need to make sure some directories have permission to `golden` user so that's why I am doing `chown -R golden`.

I can save all above commands in a file and machine name as well in a file? What is the best way to do this?

**Update:-**

My list of machines is in this file `machines.txt`:

```
somemachineA
somemachineB
```

And my commands are in this file `commands.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt-get install htop
sudo scp -r todd@machineA.host.com:/home/todd/pip /tmp/
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo pip install --no-index --find-links="file:///tmp/pip/" kazoo
sudo scp -r todd@machineA.host.com:/home/todd/parallel-gnu.tar /tmp/
sudo su
cd /tmp
tar -xvf parallel-gnu.tar
cd parallel-20101112/
sudo ./configure && make && make install
sudo mkdir /appholder
sudo chown -R golden /appholder/
sudo mkdir -p /opt/lnp
sudo scp todd@machineA.host.com:/keeper/data/release/comp.tar.gz /opt/lnp/
sudo chown -R golden /opt/lnp/
sudo mkdir -p /comp/core
sudo chown -R golden /comp/core
```

I have a script like this `execute.sh` which I am running like this `./execute.sh machines.txt`:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    echo "###################################################"
    echo "Machine Name: $line"
    scp commands.sh $line:/tmp/commands.sh
    ssh -t $line 'script /dev/null . /tmp/commands.sh'
    echo "###################################################"
done < "$1"
```

After running above, I see below error:

```
todd@testMachine:~$ ./execute.sh machines.text
###################################################
Machine Name: somemachineA
todd@somemachineA's password:
commands.sh                                                                                                                                                                                                100%  104     0.1KB/s   00:00
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
todd@somemachineA's password:
Script started, file is /dev/null
Script done, file is /dev/null
todd@somemachineA:/home/todd$ somemachineB: command not found
```

Answer (score 1):

create a script with those commands then scp the script onto each machine and run it.

eg:

```
for x in `cat list-of-hosts.txt`
do
  scp command-script $x:/tmp/command-script
  ssh -t $x 'script /dev/null . /tmp/command-script'
done
```

or to allow the script to  run in parallel:

```
for x in `cat list-of-hosts.txt`
do
  scp command-script $x:/tmp/command-script
  xterm -e ssh -t $x '/dev/null . /tmp/command-script' &
done
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. In general my machine name is not `machine1` and `machine2`. They have a different name and we cannot replace `x` in `machine.host.com`. Sorry I should have been more clear. Is there any other way to use machines? Should I create a .txt file for that and read each line as a machine name and then use it? If yes, can you provide an example how would that work?

Comment: Ok I got the file part working but when it is executing those  commands after copying the file, I am getting this error `sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified`

Comment: I tried that and it printed out like this `Script started, file is /dev/null
Script done, file is /dev/null` and then `actual machine name command not  found`. My ssh command is like this - `ssh $line 'script /dev/null . /tmp/commands.sh'`

Comment: oops,  a TTY needs to be forced, as ssh turn that off if it thinks it is non-interactive.  Add `-t` (edited)

Comment: I have updated the question, looks like it still not working and it is not executing those commands and giving error on second machine name.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would propose:

- put all those commands in a script (let's say `golden.sh`)
- In a loop run `ssh $user@machine$number 'bash -s' < golden.sh` (you need to provide $user and $number manually or make if part of another script).

If you need to login to those machines from time to time you might think about importing public ssh keys from those hosts. In that case the whole job can be fully automated as providing the password won't be required anymore.

Comment: He'll still need the password for sudo. unless he uses ssh keys for root login.